# How to set a timeout for resque jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

I need to implement a feature that lets resque jobs timeout if they are not processed within a certain time.

So lets say a job is created but can't be processed within one hour because the queue is too long and/or there is not enough workers working them off.

I wan't the job to be deleted in such a case...whats the best way to do that? Maybe there is a config parameter I'm overseeing or a 3rd party gem?

Thanks

Comment: https://rubygems.org/gems/resque-timeout is a gem that is supposed to time out the job. Not sure if it deletes or not

Comment: already checked that...it kills long running resque tasks. so not what I was looking for :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way to do this in Resque by default, but it wouldn't be hard to do yourself.

In your job do something like this:

```
def perform(id, queued_at)
  return false unless Time.parse(queued_at) >= 1.hour.ago

  ...
end
```

And to enqueue jobs, do: Resque.enqueue(MyJobClass, object.id, DateTime.now). The first line will automatically dump the job and prevent it from being performed if it was queued longer than an hour ago.

Comment: Thanks. That we'll do the job. I'm just wondering if the is a easy way to access the queued_at field directly from resque!?

Comment: I'm pretty confident Resque doesn't even bother tracking queued_at, so no, there's no way to access it unless you track it yourself.

Comment: I had to add .to_s: Time.parse(queued_at.to_s)